# Listar $_SESSION de usuários diferentes php

Tags: php, mysql, android, ajax, apache-cordova

procurei bastante e nada, existe a condição de listar todos usuários de sessions diferentes?

Por exemplo este script que uso, lista só 1 usuário.

```
<?php

  include "db.php";


   $qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT C.*,L.xname,L.email  
    FROM       clientes C
    INNER JOIN usuarios L 
    ON         L.id=C.user_id 
    WHERE      C.user_id=".$_SESSION['id']." ");

    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
       $vetor[] = $resultado;
  }    

    echo json_encode($vetor, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ); 


?>
```

Pretendo listar todos cadastrados, é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Sempre irá retornar só a sessão que estiver rodando.
Sugiro para cada um dos usuários logados, um hash no banco de dados, de tempo em tempo validar este hash, nesta mesma função apagar os hash com mais de 5, 10 ou 15 min sem validação. Seriam 2 colunas a mais HASH, DATETIMEVALIDACAO
Numa estrutura MVC, pode colocar nos construtores de cada Controller.
Então pode saber quais são as sessões ativas buscando no BD, todos usuários com hash diferente de vazio.

Comment: Beleza, não conheço esta técnica **hash no banco de dados**  tem um link direto que possa consultar, pois fiz algumas pesquisas aqui e não tive sucesso, porém enfatiza e esclarece sobre o conceito hash, mas, gostaria de um exemplo.